# HTML content is not being rendered in Visual Composer WordPress

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I have implemented a short code to display the product search form in the page built using Visual Composer.

```
add_shortcode( 'sagar-custom-search', 'sagar_custom_search' );
function sagar_custom_search() {
    $form = '<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="' . esc_url( home_url( '/'  ) ) . ' ">';
    $form .= '<div>';
    $form .= '<label class="screen-reader-text" for="s">' . __( 'Search for:', 'woocommerce' ) . '</label>';
    $form .= '<input type="text" value="' . get_search_query() . '" name="s" id="s" placeholder="' . __( 'My Search form', 'woocommerce' ) . '" />';
    $form .= '<input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="'. esc_attr__( 'Search', 'woocommerce' ) .'" />';
    $form .= '<input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="product" />';
    $form .= '</div>';
    $form .= '</form>';

    echo $form;
    echo "sagar tamang";
}
```

The form can be seen using inspect but it is not being rendered. Can anybody help figure it out.

[image]

Comment: is the form not visible in front end?

Comment: not is not, it should be along the text "sagar tamang"

Comment: form is displaying in view source, so it might be the problem of css, please double check the css from your end, because with out posting any code we can't help.

Comment: http://gudri.uchitservices.com here is the site. If you would check it out.